# How to change font of textbox drop-down menu in HTML using Alpha Anywhere

Tags: android, html, css

I am writing a mobile app for Android and iOS using the Alpha Anywhere framework. I have a dropdown textbox which currently displays two options "King Kong" and "Peter Jackson". How do I change the font size of these names in Alpha Anywhere?

[image]

If you know of a solution using JavaScript or Xbasic in the software suite that would also useful, and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a ControlBar control? If so, that is where you would style it. On the other hand, if it is simply a drop-down control in a header, you could click on the object in the UX editor, and edit it's style in the Properties column on the right.